# Have a strange issue with Google SSL cert on my box

Tags: windows, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm working on `W10 box`.

One day all Chromium based web browsers (Chrom, Opera) stopped working with any Google based services showing `"Cert is revoked"` message on SSL access.

Given Cert is:

https://censys.io/certificates?q=37839b99a1c97d649b3d931ff055eba5f1493434

What is very strange Edge browser is working well.

What's more all browers show the same Certificate (checked details) for a given web page but only Edge is working with it.

What's the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

So it's finally solved.

Somehow, have no idea why, my CERT store had 2 copies of the main signing cert called "Google Trust Services -GlobalSign Root CA-R2". 
The one used for signing Google services.
Once I delete the "bad" one all browsers work well!